# Hibernate specified cfg.xml file [/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml] does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate.cfg.xml

I have a Mave + Hibernate + Eclipse project.
My hibernate.cfg.xml in in /src/main/resources (as it should be)

This is my tree
[My tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH5cT.png)

The HibernateUtil class start the session (I've also tried to force cfg.xml as you can see in the commented part with no success)

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private final static String cfgFile ="/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static File hibernateConfig = new File(cfgFile);

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure(hibernateConfig);
//          StandardServiceRegistryBuilder srb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
//          ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = srb.build();
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            logger.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
```

This is the exception

```
2015-11-13 10:17:56.565 [main] [ERROR] Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Specified cfg.xml file [/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml] does not exist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at it.besmart.crud.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:34)
    at it.besmart.crud.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at it.besmart.parkserver.StartServer.updatePark(StartServer.java:70)
    at it.besmart.parkserver.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:33)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Specified cfg.xml file [/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml] does not exist
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlFile(ConfigLoader.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:300)
    at it.besmart.crud.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:26)
    ... 3 more
```

I've also tried to move cfg file to another dir, but i got always the same error, my pom.xml file says that /src/main/resources is a resource directory

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>/Users/mario/eshare/workspace/parkserver/src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Use relative addressing: `cfgFile ="hibernate.cfg.xml"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource tag should look like this instead:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

and you should look it up like this:

```
cfgFile = "hibernate.cfg.xml";
```

if you place it in the `WEB-INF` of the created `war` file. The `/src/main/` hierarchy definitely should not be part of the generated file.

Comment: I create a jar file, not a war, anyway yours is a good point, but I'm not able to change the effective pom.xml to use the correct paths (indeed all my directory have full paths...)